# How can I update Windows to 17763

Tags: windows, uwp, version

I need to create a project `uwp` in Visual Studio that needs an update to Winver 17763. How can I update to a new version of Windows 17763?

Comment: use this https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=799445 , an error will prevent you to upgrade due to developer mode is on, so turn off developer mode first (i experienced this issue)

Answer (score 1):

Build 17763 is known as the October 2018 Update or Redstone 5. You can download and install it using Windows Update: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028685/windows-10-get-the-update.

Or using the Update Assistant: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Answer (score 0):

Okey I find the solution: Go to `Settings -> Applications -> 
applications and features` and here unistaller Programmer mode.

Now you can update to Windows 17763.288